# Maximum call stack size exceeded with Javascript Canvas animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, requestanimationframe

I have a jsFiddle that I've been messing around with, trying to get my little game to become more organized with classes and such, but when I request an animation frame, passing in the objects (each frame does a few functions with each object), I get a Maximum call stack size error. How can I fix this without abandoning my classes?

The jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Blawkbuilder/Q5U3X/109/

the line I suspect to be the culpurit:

```
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw(p1,p2));
```

but the line the console links to occurs somewhere in jquery:

```
    } else if ( !rhtml.test( elem ) ) {
```

Fix? I'm a bit new to javascript.

(If needed, here is the previous, not class based version that still functions how I want this too)
http://jsfiddle.net/Blawkbuilder/9hmca/131/

Comment: Well, your first problem is that `requestAnimationFrame` takes a function as a parameter, but you're passing in the result of _invoking_ a function. Let me see if that is the whole problem.

Comment: As _Intredasting_ says you don't pass `draw` as callback for `requestAnimationFrame`  but you call it directly and as this line is inside of `draw` itself, you have an endless recursive call which results in the given error.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely the whole problem. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` takes a callback function with no arguments as a parameter. The reason you're getting a stack overflow is that you're providing the parameter `draw(p1, p2)` (rather than `draw`), which actually *invokes* the `draw` function, which then makes the same mistake of invoking the `draw` function ... (and so forth). You're doing it correctly in the second jsFiddle.

To get around this, you need `draw` to not take any parameters. Alternatively, create a "wrapper" function that doesn't take any parameters, which itself simply invokes draw with the appropriate parameters. The simplest way to do this do something like `requestAnimationFrame(function() {draw(p1, p2); })` as the other answer suggests.

By the way, telling you this is metaphorically giving you a fish, rather than teaching you how to fish. To really understand this, you need to understand a bit more about functional programming, which can get a little abstract. In this example, understand that functions are nothing more than objects that have the special property of being "callable" (or "invokable"). `requestAnimationFrame` is a function whose first parameter, `callback`, is another function. `requestAnimationFrame` is expecting that `callback` is callable, in other words. But you're giving it the *result* of calling the function, rather than the function itself.

The reason `function() {draw(p1, p2);}` works is that the `function() { ... }` syntax constructs an *anonymous* function -- a function without a name, but still a function that can be invoked.

Comment: You should keep the number of global variables always at a minimum. Whenever possible you should encapsulate all your variables definitions into a _private_  scope.

Comment: The issue is that I want to externalize (if thats the word) my actions away from the draw loop and into the class of the "player"- which requires me to pass in the player as an argument.

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit the answer to not suggest global variables. In JS, global variables are bad for scoping reasons and performance reasons.

Comment: well anyway, it worked. (I would love to upvote your answer, but i'm still at 5 rep)

Answer (score 5):

`requestAnimationFrame` takes a callback. You are evaluating `draw(p1, p2)` and passing its return value to `requestAnimationFrame`. You should change to something like this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function() { draw(p1, p2); });
```

This is similar to setInterval/setTimeout.

Comment: I would upvote your comment, but I dont have 15 rep yet.